# .Net MVC3 jQgrid Error "is null or not an object"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am trying to implement jqgrid in our MVC3 project. However I run into this error:-

**Microsoft JScript runtime error:  'b.jgrid.errors.model' is null or not an object.**

These are the scripts referred in the _layout.cshtml:-

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid.local-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My Controller code look like this:-

```
public ActionResult getSummaryRow(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = _context.Sales_Dashboard_summary.Where(a=>a.DateId==_dateid).Count();

            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

            var summaryRecord = _context.Sales_Dashboard_summary.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (
                            from sRec in _context.Sales_Dashboard_summary
                            where sRec.DateId == _dateid
                            select new
                            {
                                i = sRec.DateId,
                                cell = new string[] { sRec.DateId.ToString(),
                                                      sRec.ReportName, 
                                                      sRec.Month, 
                                                      sRec.tot_msr_cnt.ToString(), 
                                                      sRec.Missing_Count.ToString(), 
                                                      sRec.PubInd 
                                                    }
                            }
                        ).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my View page :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
          $("#list").jqGrid({
              url: '/Home/getSummaryRow/',
              datatype: 'json',
              mtype: 'GET',
              colNames: ['Date Id','Report Name', 'Month', 'Total Measure','Missing Measure','Published'],
              colModel: [
                      { name: 'DateId', index: 'DateId', width: 20, align: 'left' },
                      { name: 'ReportName', index: 'ReportName', width: 40, align: 'left' },
                      { name: 'Month', index: 'Month', width: 40, align: 'left' },
                      { name: 'tot_msr_cnt', index: 'tot_msr_cnt', width: 20, align: 'right' },
                      { name: 'missing_count', index: 'missing_count', width: 20, align: 'right'}],
              pager: jQuery('#pager'),
              rowNum: 10,
              rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
              sortname: 'Month',
              sortorder: "desc",
              viewrecords: true,
              imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
              caption: 'Sales Dashboard'
          });
      }); 
     </script>  



<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>

 <table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
 <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In any way you should not include two different versions of jQuery (1.7.2 and 1.5.2) on one page. Moreover you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to have more readable error message.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the reply. I figured out the problem. It was very simple, the number of columns in ColNames were not matching the colModel.